# Nested class' access to enclosing class' private data members

Tags: c++, nested

I'm having trouble implementing a nested class who's constructor is initialized with some of the enclosing class' private data members.

Example:

```
Header File:
class Enclosing {
   //...Public members
   //...Private members
   int x, int y
   class Inner; // Declaration for nested class
};

Impl. File:
// Stuff...
class Enclosing::Inner {
    explicit Inner() : foo(x), bar(y) // foo and bar are data members of Inner
    //...
};
```

I get an `invalid use of non-static data member` error. Is there something I'm missing when it comes to nested class access to its enclosing class' members?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Member `x` and `y` are non-static data member of `Enclosing`, which means that they only exist within a concrete object of `Enclosing` class. Without a concrete object, neither `x` nor `y` exist. Meanwhile, you are trying to refer to `x` and `y` without an object. That can't be done, which is what the compiler is trying to tell you.

If you want to initialize members `Inner::foo` and `Inner::bar` from `x` and `y`, you have to pass a concrete object of `Enclosing` type into the `Inner`s constructor. For example

```
class Enclosing::Inner {    
  explicit Inner(const Enclosing& e) : foo(e.x), bar(e.y) 
    {}
  //...
};
```

Extra note: in the original C++98 the inner class has no special privileges is accessing the outer class. With C++98 compiler you'd either have to give the inner class the necessary privileges (friendship) or expose the members `x` and `y` as public. However, this situation was classified as a [defect](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#45) in C++98, and it was decided that inner classes should have full access to outer class members (even private ones). So, whether you have to do anything extra with regard to access privileges depends on your compiler.

Comment: Thanks. I read about the defect in C++98 while researching it on my own, and wasn't sure what to make of it. Thanks for clearing everything up.

Answer (score 10):

The  problem with your code is [not visibility](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#45), as pointed out by [AndreyT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604853/nested-class-access-to-enclosing-class-private-data-members/1605132#1605132), but that an instance of the `Inner` class is not bound to a concrete instance of the `Enclosing` class. The In other words when constructing an `Inner` the compiler has no way of know which object to take the `x` and `y` values from.

You will have to explicitly provide an instance of the `Enclosing` class to the constructor of the `Inner` class as so:

```
class Enclosing
{
private:
  int x;
  int y;

  class Inner
  {
  private:
    int foo;
    int bar;

  public:
    explicit Inner(const Enclosing& e)
      : foo(e.x), bar(e.y) 
    { }
  };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

nested class can't access privet data member of enclosing class.compiler show a error if we try to access privet member of enclosing class, it can only access the public data member of enclosing class.....