# Comparators in C++ and priority queues

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can inner classes access private variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486099/can-inner-classes-access-private-variables)

So I'm trying to use a priority queue, and in the context of this queue I want to define an integer i to be "less" than another integer j if D[i] < D[j].  How can I do this?  (D is a data member of an object)

So far I have

```cpp
/* This function gets the k nearest neighbors for a user in feature
 * space.  These neighbors are stored in a priority queue and then
 * transferred to the array N. */
void kNN::getNN() {
    int r;
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, CompareDist> NN;

    /* Initialize priority queue */
    for (r = 0; r < k; r++) {
        NN.push(r);
    }

    /* Look at the furthest of the k users.  If current user is closer,
     * replace the furthest with the current user. */
    for (r = k; r < NUM_USERS; r++) {
        if (NN.top() > r) {
            NN.pop();
            NN.push(r);
        }
    }

    /* Transfer neighbors to an array. */
    for (r = 0; r < k; r++) {
        N[r] = NN.top();
        NN.pop();
    }
}
```

And in kNN.hh:

```
class kNN {

private:
    struct CompareDist {
        bool operator()(int u1, int u2) {
            if (D[u1] < D[u2])
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    };
...
```

However, this is giving me the error

```
kNN.hh: In member function ‘bool kNN::CompareDist::operator()(int, int)’:
kNN.hh:29: error: invalid use of nonstatic data member ‘kNN::D’
```

What can I do about this?  It seems that C++ doesn't like it if I refer to specific objects in the comparator, but I have no idea how to solve this without referring to D.

Thanks!

Comment: This question isn't actually about priority queues and comparators, but about how inner classes can access data members of enclosing classes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486099/can-inner-classes-access-private-variables, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604853/nested-class-access-to-enclosing-class-private-data-members

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may pass a reference to the `D` object into the constructor of the `CompareDist` object, and then use that `D` object in `operator()`.

In this sample, I store a pointer to `D`. Depending upon the type of `D`, you may want to store a copy of `D`. (If `D` is a raw array, the syntax in my sample can be simplified.)

```
struct CompareDist {
    const DType* pD;
    CompareDist(const DType& D) : pd(&D) {}
    bool operator()(int u1, int u2) {
        return (*pD)[u1] < (*pD)[u2];
    }
};

priority_queue<int, vector<int>, CompareDist> NN(CompareDist(D));
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, now I've read your question better and I can update the answer: the problem is that `D` is an object that is contained inside an instance of `kNN`, hence it is not `static` and can't be accessed from a static context.

You can solve the problem by using a static reference to D inside the class, something like

```
// .h
class kNN {
  static Type* current;
  ..

    struct CompareDist {
      bool operator()(int u1, int u2) {
        if ((*current)[u1] < (*current)[u2])
          return true;
        else
          return false;
      }
    };
}

// .cpp
Type *kNN::current = NULL;

void kNN::method()
{
  kNN::current = D; // beforing using the comparator
  ..
}
```

In addition signature should use elements by const reference, eg

```
bool operator()(const int &u1, const int &u2)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm really confused about this.  When am I referring to a specific instance of a collection?  Also why do I need to pass a reference to an integer if it's just an integer and not an object?

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect your specific situation, you need to pass by reference to avoid copying the value.

Comment: using static variables like this is not a good practice