# Nested class member access on C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, g++-4.7

In C++11, I am trying to access a member variable of an enclosing class from a nested class in the following way:

```
struct Enclosing {
    int a;
    struct Nested {
        int f() {
            return a;
        }
    };
};
```

Even this doesn't compile using g++4.7.2 with -std=c++11, producing error messages of this form:

```
error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Enclosing::a'
```

As far as I understand, C++11 treats a nested class as a member of the class, so that supposedly a nested class can access every other member of the enclosing class. Did I do something wrong? Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

While my question seems to have an answer below, I am not convinced this shall be flagged as duplicate.

I am aware of discussions on the relationship between nested classes and enclosing classes before the C++11 standard, after a lot of searching before posting a question.

Previous relevant discussions like this cite some "updates" in C++11, e.g. [C++ nested classes accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998369/c-nested-classes-accessibility)

But it was not very clear, at least from answers I've read, the full extent that C++11 is "different" from older versions on this matter.

Technically the solution to my question exists in older threads such as
[Nested class' access to enclosing class' private data members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604853/nested-class-access-to-enclosing-class-private-data-members), a fact that had to be pointed out, however inane it makes me seem. But I did not come by any such answer that puts C++11 into context; at least, I don't think my question can be fairly deemed a "duplicate" of a question asked before the C++11 standard.

Comment: No, it's not treated as a member of the class, it's just scoped inside of it like anything else. You'll need an instance of Enclosing to access it's members.

Comment: A nested class *is* a member of the surrounding class. It's just not a *data member*, and instances of that nested class aren't necessarily data members of the surrounding class either. AFAIK that has not changed between C++98 and C++11.

Comment: *"a nested class can access every other member of the enclosing class"* Every member of the class has access to the *names* of the private members of the class. (Access to *names* is what C++ access control is about.)

Comment: You may want to get the latest stable version of the toolchain, just FYI. If I recall correctly, the version your using doesn't have a complete C++11 implementation.

Comment: For more info about what I was talking about with C++11 support, see https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close this question I'll take this as an answer:

"No, it's not treated as a member of the class, it's just scoped inside of it like anything else. You'll need an instance of Enclosing to access it's members."

- this and several other comments addresses the problem in my code. Basically this is something that remains true for C++11.

Comment: I don't see a viable reason for this post. Answering to your own question is certainly encouraged, but not when the rundown of your answer is: "I have  accepted the answer given". I  think you should instead accept the answer that brought you to this conclusion. This borderlines on: "This is not an answer, It should instead be a comment"

Comment: The answers I'd like to accept were given as comments to my question post. Those posting the comment may not think their comments have enough merit to be an "answer", but they are indeed the most relevant to the problem I had in mind. The only other answer post is not one that I consider the most appropriate to accept. In short, the reason for this post is that I would like to formally mark this question as "resolved", and I can't find a way other than citing a comment in an answer post.

Comment: In theory those are definitely valid reasons for a separate answer. In this particular case I just don't see anything in your answer that was not covered in the other answer. If that is included by "several other comments address the problem in my code", then you should cite those comments so that someone with your same problem can see them in your answer. Information that addresses a question should ultimately be included in an answer. Comments are unreliable for that on the long term. It is perfectly ok to add in your question information left by others in  comments.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the change within C++11 from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types);

> Declarations in a nested class can use only type names, static
> members, and enumerators from the enclosing class (until C++11)
>
> Declarations in a nested class can use any members of the enclosing
> class, following the usual usage rules for the non-static members.
> (since C++11)

```
int x,y; // globals
class enclose { // enclosing class
    int x; // note: private members
    static int s;
 public:
    struct inner { // nested class
        void f(int i) {
            x = i; // Error: can't write to non-static enclose::x without instance
            int a = sizeof x; // Error until C++11,
                              // OK in C++11: operand of sizeof is unevaluated,
                              // this use of the non-static enclose::x is allowed.
            s = i;   // OK: can assign to the static enclose::s
            ::x = i; // OK: can assign to global x
            y = i;   // OK: can assign to global y
        }
        void g(enclose* p, int i) {
            p->x = i; // OK: assign to enclose::x
        }
    };
};
```

In brief, within C++11, nested class can refer to types and static members of its enclosing class. In addition, it can refer to non-static members only when object of the enclosing class is given to the nested class. A nested class has access to members of its enclosing class including private members.