# Private nested class accessing private function of outer class

Tags: c++, oop, inner-classes

Simplified version of my code

```
class Outer
{
private:
    double Foo(double a=0; double b=1);

    class Inner
    {
    public:
        Inner()
        {
            mX = Foo(2, 3);
        }
    private:
        double mX;
    };
};
```

My problem is, Inner cannot access the Foo function. I have looked around various sites regarding what needs to be done. I saw on one page that using the friend keyword could be useful, but I couldn't seem to apply it properly.

I'd like to keep the Inner class private in Outer because of how the rest of my code is structured.

I don't think this is a copy of another question, but if I'm wrong, my apologies.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested class' access to enclosing class' private data members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604853/nested-class-access-to-enclosing-class-private-data-members)

Answer (score 1):

`Outer::Foo` is a non-static member function; you need an instance of `Outer` to be called on, the inner class doen't have it implicitly (like java). e.g.

```
class Outer
{
private:
    double Foo(double a=0; double b=1);

    class Inner
    {
    public:
        Inner()
        {
            Outer o;
            mX = o.Foo(2, 3);
        }
    private:
        double mX;
    };
};
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Thank you fo the helpful and speedy response, Out of curiosity, given I have an instance of Outer, how would I access a private member variable of Outer. Again, I'm sure it,s something simple.

Comment: @T.Smith I might not get your question correctly; inside `Inner`, you could access the `private` members of `Outer` directly, if you have an instance of `Outer`, as showed in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some mistakes:

```
double Foo(double a=0; double b=1);
```

`;` is not a delimiter between function's parameters, use `,` instead.

```
mX = Foo(2, 3);
```

`Foo` is non-static function, which means it object interface related. You can't call it without specified which object it relates to.
To fix it you can both create an object and call this function of the related object, or make this function a static one.

Example of creating an object:

```
class Inner {
public:
    Inner() {
        Outer o; // Consider making it a class member object, so in each call / use it will relate to the same one. Be aware that in this case you will need to use a pointer to the outer class, due to 'incomplete type' error.
        mX = o.Foo(2, 3);
    }
private:
    double mX;
};
```

Example of making it a static function:

```
class Outer {
private:
    static double Foo(double a=0, double b=1);

    class Inner {
    public:
        Inner() {
            mX = Outer::Foo(2, 3);
        }
    private:
        double mX;
    };
};
```

Consider also the following ways of giving mX its value, in case of static function `Foo`:

```
class Inner {
public:
    Inner() {}
private:
    double mX = Outer::Foo(2, 3); // Recommended by Cpp guidelines.
};
```

Or:

```
class Inner {
public:
    Inner() : mX(Outer::Foo(2, 3)) {} // Using initialize list

private:
    double mX;
};
```

**References:**
[C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rp-direct)